# Change HTML content based on POST form data

Tags: go

I am using github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter with multiple routes accepting POST requests via various forms. Each route func processes the form data and should result in a change in the attribute of certain tags in index.html.

For example,

```
func formOneRoute(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
// check form data and execute conditional changes
if ... {
    file, _ := os.ReadFile("index.html")
    file = []byte(strings.Replace(string(file), "<a class=\"xxx\" href=\"#"+hhh+"\">", "<a class=\"yyy\" href=\"#"+hhh+"\">", -1))
    _ = os.WriteFile("index.html", file, 0644)
}
}
```

This does work but feels like a very MacGyvered solution. I also am curious if this could create a problem when the users submit forms through different routes at the same time and the read/write happening simultaneously in different goroutines and borking up the index.html file.

What is the idiomatic way of doing this?

Comment: This approach is racy. You should generate the html file using a template based on data stored somewhere that can handle transactions, like a database.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I will look into that, although for the time being, to fix the race condition, is there a way to make the read/write across goroutines sequential, meaning the goroutine waits until the previous one has completed successfully?

Comment: Yes, use a mutex. It will work as long as you have a single of this app running.

Comment: to check for yourself - use the `-race` flag during testing - `fuzz` testing also helps